# UIButton actions triggered by all touch events on iOS simulator 5s

Tags: ios, xcode9.2

I'm having this strange problem in the iOS simulator 5s that the  button actions are triggered by *all* touch events on the screen (other simulators on Xcode 9.2 works fine though).

The actions are declared in this manner:

`[aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doSomething:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

But the example method

`- (void)doSomething:(id)sender`

is called when the table is scrolled or the map is zoomed for example. The `sender` object is however always `aButton`.

It's a bug of course, but's a bit scary one. It totally messes up the navigation and the logic in the app and I don't have any real device iPhone 5s to test on.

Does anyone else experience the same, or can shed some light on the subject?

Comment: Have you resetting the simulator ?

Comment: @Nitish yes, I have tried "Erase all Content and Settings..", have cleaned build and build folder and deleted and reinstalled app. No effect.

Comment: How you are adding button?

Comment: Hm, interestingly I'm having trouble only with buttons added to view with auto layout (having a mix of layout strategies in the app). Might mean something... but why only on 5s?